# SSL Encryption Issue

Tags: php, html, mysql, ssl, server

I have hosted an ecommerce website with the OpenCart script at www.medicosales.in

I am facing some errors.

1. The website when opened by typing medicosales.in is NOT automatically resolving to https:// where I have seen in SSL secured sites that just by typing yourdomain.com the URL automatically takes https://
2. It's showing this message 
   [image: message]

How to solve it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. You should set up your `.htaccess` file if you're using Apache, or similar if you're using another webserver to rewrite your URLs to include `https://` if they do not already. This will force the user's browser to access via the correct protocol.

For Apache place the following code into the top of your `.htaccess` file in your document root for the site ensuring `mod_rewrite` is enabled.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

2. Whenever you load a resource externally e.g. via something like `<img src="http://example.com/myimage.jpg" ...` you must ensure that the protocol is HTTPS also otherwise your browser will give you that message since the resource was not loaded securely.

The way to fix this is ensure that all externally linked resources have their URLs prefixed with `//` and not `http://`. This way the browser will use the current protocol to fetch the resource.

**Thanks @davidgiga1993 for pointing out `//` rather than using `https://`**

Comment: It would be better to use // as protocol string. This way the current protocol is always used. See "network path reference" and  RFC 3986 for more information.

Comment: @davidgiga1993 Good point, forgot about that; edited original post.

Comment: I got this method while browsing some sites and I got this problem solved. However since your answer is as same as the required one I accepted your answer. Thanks... :)

Answer (score 0):

It is not automatic. You need to send a 302/301 redirect back to the user pointing to the https URL.

Comment: I'd recommend a 301 in favour of 302 since that will be better in terms of search engine rankings being credited to the SSL version of the site.